# Telebot. Мне нужно внести в список айди пользователей, написавших боту

Tags: python, list, telebot

Я попробовал сделать это через append, но в списке появляется только одно айди
извиняюсь, если вопрос глупый. Я невнимательный и впервые что-то делаю подобное, читал только краткие гайды

```
import telebot
from telebot import types
import random
bot = telebot.TeleBot('тут длинная хреновина')
@bot.message_handler(commands = ['start'])
def start(message):
    print('Start done')
    mesg=bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Для начала диалога напишите "p f"')
    bot.register_next_step_handler(mesg, find_p)
@bot.message_handler(content_types=["text"])
def find_p(message):
    if message.text=='p f':
        global id_list
        id_list=[]
        id_list.append(message.chat.id)
        print(id_list)ц
bot.polling(timeout=0)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Первая ошибка: уберите хендлер @bot.message_handler(content_types=["text"]) перед функцией find_p(message), так как эта функция исполниться все равно.
А информация о пользователях получается по таким формулам:

```
message.from_user.id
message.from_user.first_name
message.from_user.last_name
message.from_user.username
```

То есть

```
id_list.append(message.from_user.id)
```